# Automatically change domain name in URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm creating a mirror for my website and I need to automatically change domain name in URLs on my new website, using some .htaccess command on my new site.

What I need is to change all links from www.old.com/any_link.html to www.new.com/any_link.html for all users on www.new.com without changing anything in database (having the same database for both sites). So that I get two independent websites www.old.com and www.new.com working at the same time.

I know about redirect 301 from old site to the new one, but I need redirecting INSIDE new website, without changing anything on the old one.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

try writing this on `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Than does not work, sorry. Redirects too many times, if I post it in new site root directory.

Comment: it should be written at `old site` htaccess file to be redirected to new site

Comment: Yeah, it seems there is no way to do it. For some security reasons probably.